# Sync volume control?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, volume-control, volume

I'm running 7 on my Galaxy s6. Is there an app or setting I could change to where all the volumes are the same when I change them? 
(Ex when the media is half way, all of them are half way)

Answer (score 2):

[Volume Sync- Sync your Volume](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.reactle.ringandnotificationvolumesync) does exactly that

It can sync all the volumes - Notification, Media, System, Alarm and In call volume together or selectively as you want

I didn't try them all synced at same time but it worked well -just installed, tested briefly

Comment: Technically this app only syncs your devices volumes to the ringer volume and not the other way around.  To quote the app "The app will sync all the selected volumes below to match the ringer volume when it's changed.." This can becoming frustrating because if you adjust the "media volume" while listening to music for example it doesn't actually update "ringer volume" while it does update the "media volume" when adjusting "ringer volume."  I honestly though the app was broken until I read the fine print.  I am still looking for one that just syncs media & ringer volume.