# Default volume key control LineageOS

Tags: rooting, 7.0-nougat, lineageos

So I prefer how my iPhone works in that the volume keys adjust the media volume.

Samsung has an option for this called ["Default volume key control."](http://inside-galaxy.blogspot.com/2017/08/samsung-galaxy-s8-how-to-change-default.html?m=1)

Is there a way to do this on a rooted device?

Basically I don't like how there are 2 separate volumes that I have to deal with.  I just want one.  I put my phone on silent when I don't want it to ring so I'm not concerned about the ringtone volume.

Comment: There is an solution [here] (https://android.stackexchange.com/a/188233/131553)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Media volume only](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=catchpower.gogo.mediavolumeonly&hl=en) does exactly this but does require accessibility settings.  Supposedly it doesn't drain your battery but I'm not 100% sure.

There is other options here https://www.xda-developers.com/apps-to-master-your-volume-buttons/
I experimented with a couple apps but ultimately many of them don't for example if your screen is off.