# Android 9 set volume keys to adjust ringer by default

Tags: volume-control, 9.0-pie, volume

I have a OnePlus 3T, and recently updated it to LineageOS 16, from 15.1 - however I imagine this applies to any device with Android 9.

I realise that Android 9 has changed the default behaviour of the volume keys, to adjust the media volume by default. Whilst I can appreciate that some users might find this useful, I much preferred the ringer volume being changed by default and the media volume changing when media was being played. It seems like now there is no way to change the ringer volume using the hardware keys.

Is there any way to undo this change in defaults and make the volume keys adjust the ringer volume by default? Essentially I want to do the *opposite* of [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/190832). Ideally I'd like not to have to install some questionable app to do it, I have root access so can use that if there's some command that I can change.

Or at the very least, is there a way to stop the ringtone from playing when I change volume from the "Sound" setting menu? Typically when I am changing the ringer volume I'm trying to reduce the amount of noise I might make, but changing the ringer volume through the "Sound" menu causes Android start playing my ringtone, which is very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I was very frustrated when Android 9 changed the volume buttons to control the media volume all the time so I developed an app to fix this and make the volume buttons control the ringtone and notification volume as it used to. It's free and you can install it from here: [https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softstackdev.volumeFix ]

Let me know if you need any help to use it.

Comment: Thank you for the app, it appears to work. Another detail that you may want to add is the ability to adjust ringer volume in small steps instead of the current large steps in Android 9.

Comment: @HugoSALINASALIAGA, unfortunately my options are very limited but I will see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use MacroDroid to change modes triggered off another setting.  I just installed it for another purpose and haven't explored all the possibilities

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid